# Android discount app is not running

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple discount app for android, but my app is not running and hope you guys can help me to figure whats wrong with it.
I am new to android development, so maybe I am doing a lot of things wrong and here's my code.

Right now I am just just working on the RadioButton part, where I click the Button, let's say 10%, then it will display the correctly saved amount and the total

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private double listedPrice;
private int discountPrecentID;
private RadioGroup discount;
private double discountPrecent;
// private RadioButton discountPrecent;
private TextView savedAmount;
private TextView payAmount;
private EditText userInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    listedPrice = Double.parseDouble(userInput.getText().toString());
    savedAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    payAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    discount = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    // SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    // seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    discountPrecentID = discount.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    // discountPrecent = (RadioButton) findViewById(discountPrecentID);
    switch (discountPrecentID) {
    case R.id.radio0:{
        discountPrecent = 0.10;
        savedAmount.setText("$" + listedPrice * discountPrecent);
        payAmount.setText("$"
                + (listedPrice - (listedPrice * discountPrecent)));
        break;
    }
    case R.id.radio1:{
        discountPrecent = 0.25;
        savedAmount.setText("$" + listedPrice * discountPrecent);
        payAmount.setText("$"
                + (listedPrice - (listedPrice * discountPrecent)));
        break;
    }
    case R.id.radio2:{
        discountPrecent = 0.50;
        savedAmount.setText("$" + listedPrice * discountPrecent);
        payAmount.setText("$"
                + (listedPrice - (listedPrice * discountPrecent)));
        break;
    }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What is/isn't working? Where are you stuck?

Comment: not sure how i already got -2 rep from posting an honest question? I spent a lot of time to write this and people just give me negative rep without saying anything? i am sad.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would venture to guess it's because you didn't explain your problem.

Comment: when i run this, it keep saying " unfortunately, discount calculator has stopped." and the logCat say somthing about Double being a problem, but eclipse didn't say my code has any problems

Comment: Then there will be an exception in your logcat...post that.

Comment: Thanks, i think the problem was the switch statement. after i changed the switch to if, at least the problem is running now.

Comment: I have already edited my question and i think what i asked was really clear and i got an answer from someone which solved my problem so I am not sure how i got question ban from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely your problem

```
listedPrice = Double.parseDouble(userInput.getText().toString());
```

The user hasn't had a chance to enter something with this code in `onCreate()` so unless you have something hard-coded, you will get a `NumberFormatException`. You need to place that code in an `onClick()` or some other event after the user has had a chance to enter something.

You should also do some error-checking such as putting it inside of a `try/catch`.

```
try
{
    listedPrice = Double.parseDouble(userInput.getText().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // do something if invalid double
}
```

When posting here, you need to clearly state what is/isn't working as expected and what your problem is. Also, if your app crashes then there will be output in the logcat and you need to post that so we can easily see what/where the problem is.

Eclipse didn't say you have any problem because this is a runtime error which means that Eclipse didn't see anything wrong at compile time. Meaning your syntax is correct, as far as Eclipse knows, but your logic is not.